# Auto resizing the label according to the words

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel, autoresizingmask

I would like to resize the label font according to the number of words in the label field. How do i do that? I can use a fixed size and it doesn't look nice. It will be best if it works fine for both iOS5 and iOS6.

Need some guidance. Thanks

EDIT:

```
NSArray *versionCompatibility = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    if ( 6 == [[versionCompatibility objectAtIndex:0] intValue] ) { 

        // Put iOS-6 code here
        titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;

    } else { 

        // Put iOS-5 code here
        titleLabel.minimumFontSize = 5;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as this:

```
if(yourLabel.text.length <10){
    yourLabel.font=[yourLabel.font fontWithSize:20]
}
else if(yourLabel.text.length <15){
    yourLabel.font=[yourLabel.font fontWithSize:15]
}
else { //>20
    yourLabel.font=[yourLabel.font fontWithSize:10]
}
```

Alternatively,

Check that your label is set to automatically resize. In IB, it's called "Autoshrink". Programmatically: it is called `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`

Comment: so i can put it as [yourlabel  adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth]; am i right?

Comment: have a try and let me know

Comment: doesn't help. need to use other method...

Comment: what about conditional fontSizing?

Comment: there is no autoresizing of fonts for iOS5 is it? only for iOS6?

Comment: sorry lakesh, am very new to ios, still learning, i am mac osx developer ;(

Comment: same here.. let's learn together...

Comment: send me add req in gtalk, address in my profile